# exception handling - ruby retry loop in python

Tags: python, exception, resque-retry

How to retry a loop in python after getting the exception in ruby u use

```
begin
    a.each do |s|
    end
rescue
      sleep 2
        retry 
end
```

I will use sleep time and just use retry the loop after getting excpetion now i want to do this in python

I know code for exception handling

```
try:
   for i in w:
   #Loop code
exception e:
```

How to retry the loop if there is any exception?
       #How to retry the loop if any exception occurs

Answer (score -1):

you can create a function and call it:

```
def my_func():
    try:
        for i in w:
            #Loop code
    except:
        # here take care of exception, try to fix it, when it occurs
        my_funct()
```

if you don't want to start again:

```
try:
    for i in w:
        #Loop code
    except:
        # here take care of exception, try to fix it, when it occurs
```

Comment: lets say loop is processing at 1400 array if error occurs the function will start from 0th array right...instead i want to retry that particular array of loop(1400)

Comment: Thats why in comment i said take care of exception and fix it

Answer (score -1):

What it seems your looking for is a recursive function. Something like,

```
# retries = 3
def do(x):
    try:
        y = something(x)
    except Exception as err:
        # while retries > 0:
        #    retries -= 1
            do(x)    
    else:
        print(y)
```

Note this will create an endless loop of retries unless you set a limiter somehow like the one I commented out.